# Define LESS variable from string

Tags: less, mixins

I'm trying to write a mixin that returns a variable for converting px to em. I've toyed with a few things, but ultimately i'd like to call a mixin and get a return value similar to SASS's functions. Based on on return values here: http://www.lesscss.org/#-return-values, I can only define a variable once as a return value. Example:

**Mixin**

```
.px-to-emz( @size, @base: @font-size-base ){
    @em: round( unit( (@size / @base), ~"em" ), 3 );
}
```

**Call it:**

```
.foo {
    font-size: @em;
    .px-to-emz(10, 16px);

    height: @em;
    .px-to-emz(200, 16px);
}
```

Fine, if you want to only return one variable, but if i want to return multiple variables I need to define new variable names. Here's what i'd ideally like to do

**Mixin:**

```
.px-to-ems( @size, @var: 'em', @base: @font-size-base ){
    ~'@{var}': round( unit( (@size / @base), ~"em" ), 3 );
}
```

**Call it:**

```
.foo {
    font-size: @font-size;
    .px-to-ems(10, 'font-size', 16px);

    height: @height;
    .px-to-ems(200, 'height', 16px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### #1

So far the best known solution for this problem is to put each mixin call into its own scope:

```less
.px-to-ems(@size, @base: @font-size-base) {
    @-: round(unit((@size / @base), em), 3);
}

.foo {
    .-() {font-size: @-; .px-to-ems( 10, 16px)}
    .-() {height:    @-; .px-to-ems(200, 16px)}
    .-;
}
```

Replace `@-` and `.-` with whatever identifiers you find suitable.

#### #2

The other way around is to use recently added (Less 1.6.x) property interpolation feature:

```less
.px-to-ems(@property, @size, @base: @font-size-base) {
    @{property}: round(unit((@size / @base), em), 3);
}

.foo {
    .px-to-ems(font-size, 10, 16px);
    .px-to-ems(height,   200, 16px);
}
```

It's more clean than #1 if you simply need to assign the "function" result to a property.